# Как отметить чекбокс в Freemarker template

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, freemarker

Здраствуйте, друзья,
Я использую шаблонизатор Freemarker(java) и мне нужно отобразить отмеченные чекбоксы. Я ожидаю увидеть что отмеченные чекбоксы помечаются обычной галочкой (юникод "U+2714"), но вместо этого после работы моего кода я вижу что чекбоксы обозначены знаком вопроса (юникод U+003F). Мне нужно видеть обычную галочку как при работе с чистым html или просто значок "Х" тоже сойдёт, но ни в коем случае не знак "?". Мой код на данный момент:

```
<#list labels as checklabel> 
<div>
<input type="checkbox" id="checklabel" name="checklabel" checked="true">
<label for="checklabel">${checklabel}</label>
</div>
</#list
```

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой, или может подскажите что делаю не правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте `&#10003;`
Вот тут список есть html символов https://htmlweb.ru/html/symbols.php